# PUGXMultiUserBundle and Registration form embedded

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms, formcollection, pugxmultiuserbundle

I use PUGXMultiUserBundle because I have two type of user: CustomerUser and ShopUser.
ShopUser has a OneToMany relationship to Location(address,city...).

I need to save all data to tables (shop and location) from only RegistrationShopUserFormType. How can i do this with PUGX?

I've tried to use Form embedded and form collection, but I hasn't a good result.
Have you got any idea?

**EDIT**

Here the code:

Form/:

RegistrationShopUserFormType.php

```
<?php


namespace AppBundle\Form;
use AppBundle\Entity\ShopUser;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseRegistrationFormType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class RegistrationShopUserFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('shopName')

        ;

    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'user_shop';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => ShopUser::class,
        ));
    }

}
```

LocationFormType.php

```
<?php


namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Branch;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class LocationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('address')
                ->add('city')
                ->add('cap')
                ->add('lat')
                ->add('lng')
            ;
        $builder->add('shop', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => RegistrationShopUserFormType::class
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'location';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Location::class,
        ));
    }


}
```

Entity/:
ShopUser.php (from PUGMultiUserBundle) -without getter and setter-

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "username", targetClass = "AppBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.username.already_used")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "email", targetClass = "AppBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.email.already_used")
 */
class ShopUser extends User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
     */
    protected $vat;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $shopName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
     */
    protected $logo;

}
```

Location.php -without some getter and setter-

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Location
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="location", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id_UNIQUE", columns={"id"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_location_shop1_idx", columns={"shop_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Location
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cap", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $cap;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lat", type="float", precision=10, scale=6, nullable=false)
     */
    private $lat;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lng", type="float", precision=10, scale=6, nullable=false)
     */
    private $lng;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\ShopUser
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ShopUser")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     * @Assert\Type(type="AppBundle\Entity\ShopUser")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     *
     *
     */
    private $shop;

    /**
     * @param ShopUser $shop
     */
    public function setShop(ShopUser $shop)
    {
        $this->shop = $shop;
    }


    /**
     * @return ShopUser
     */
    public function getShop()
    {
        return $this->shop;
    }
```

Controller/:

RegistrationShopUserController.php

```
<?php


namespace AppBundle\Controller;


use AppBundle\Entity\Branch;
use AppBundle\Entity\ShopUser;
use AppBundle\Form\BranchFormType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Request;

class RegistrationShopUserController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction(){


        return $this->container
            ->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')
            ->register(ShopUser::class);


    }
}
```

In my opinion the problem is in the RegistrationShopUserController, but I don't know how fix it. Help, please.

Comment: Show what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: I've updated the post @JasonRoman

Comment: Okay - you mentioned you're not getting a good result.  Can you post the result you are getting and what you are expecting?

Comment: I need a registration shop user form where I'll can save also the shop location in its table. So when i'll submit registration shop form I'll have the data in ShopUser and Location Entities.

But this code doesn't work like I need. @JasonRoman

Comment: Is there any error when you go throught the registration process?

Comment: No. the shopregister form register the shop, but does not view the fields to register the location. Logic does not work! @JanRydrych

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue!

In the RegistrationShopUserFormType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('shopName')
            ->add('mainLocation', LocationFormType::class);


        ;

    }
```

LocationFormType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('address')
            ->add('city')
            ->add('cap')
        ;

}
```

I added in ShopUser.php

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Location", mappedBy="shop", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $locations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->locationss = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLocations()
    {
        return $this->locations;
    }


    public function getMainLocation()
    {
        return $this->locations->first() ? $this->locations->first() : null;
    }

    public function setMainLocation(Location $location)
    {
        if ($this->locations->contains($location)) {
            return;
        }

        $this->locations[] = $location;
        $branch->setShop($this);
    }
```

It works! I hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have one-direction one-to-many relationship between the `Location` entity and the `ShopUser` entity. When you create the `shopUser` object in the controller, is simply "doesn't know" that there should be some relationship to the `Location`.

The solution is, that you have to define a property in the `ShopUser` entity class which will contain relationship to the `Location` entity class (many-to-one is IMHO what you want).
Also think about how to handle that property when a new shopUser object is created - if you want to create a new location each time a new user registers, then simply create and assign a new location object in the `ShopUser` entity class constructor.

(More complex solution would be needed if you'll want to create new location and  also select from existing locations during a new user registration.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need OneToMany between ShopUser and Location. 
ShopUser has One/Many locations.
How can I solve it?
@JanRydrych